# change src of image from a php page through js

Tags: javascript, php

I have an image generated from another php page

```
         <img style="margin:9px 0 0 16px;" src="sample.php" width="87" height="59" id="imagid">
```

a captcha image is created each time.On each refresh a different image is generated.
But what I want is to put a button there which changes the image without refreshing the whole page.

```
        <input type="button" value="refresh"  onclick="refresh();">
```

and the my js code is

```
         function refresh(){

         document.getElementById("imagid").src="sample.php";
          }
```

It doesn't work,how to change the image src by js

Comment: You can use AJAX, XMLHttpRequest object to get data from server without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: try to use setAttribute method instead of just .src = "..." http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_setattribute.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your JS code you're trying to change the "src" attribute of the button, you need to apply the id to the image, not the button.

What you need to do is have the following :

```
<img style="margin:9px 0 0 16px;" src="sample.php" width="87" height="59" id="imagid">
<input type="button" value="refresh" id="imagid" onclick="refresh();">

<script>
function refresh() {
    document.getElementById("imagid").src = "sample2.php";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<img style="margin:9px 0 0 16px;" src="sample.php" width="87" height="59" id="imageid">
<input type="button" value="refresh" id="buttonid" onclick="refresh();">

<script>
$('#buttonid').click(function()
{
    $('#imageid').attr('src','sample2.php');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that image has been cached by browser because of its MIME type.

there are various ways to tackle it,

1)use different page name altogether,sample1.php,sample2.php.....
But you cannot create infinite number of page.

2)Use salting in URL, ie sample.php?rand=1,sample.php?rand?=2....
This rand parameter will keep updating all the time and on each request to server you will generate new image.

There are other advanced ways also ,but this are the one to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here.You have not assigned id to your image tag and in your js code you are trying by button id.

```
<img style="margin:9px 0 0 16px;" src="sample.php" width="87" height="59" id="imageid">
function refresh(){
         document.getElementById("imagid").src="sample.php";
}
```

Note : 
Make sure you the IDs for button and image tag.No two elements should have same Ids.

Hope this helps...